# Word to describe being useful to many people

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am trying to find a word to describe a project I am working on. This project has one function, but will be useful to as many people as possible (as many people as meet the requirements to use the project). I would like to use it in the context of something like the following sentence:

```
"My application is adjective, adjective, and ______________."
```

Does anyone know of a word that would fit here? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe, instead of finding an adjective to describe the _application_, you should focus on describing the _users_; e.g.: _"My application will be useful to a **wide audience**."_

Comment: I bet a thesaurus would gives lots of suggestions for 'useful'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a word that describes its precious nature? eg: invaluable, indispensable

Comment: I second these nominations, particulary from a marketing perspective.  I wouldn't use them both, but one or the other fits nicely in the O.P.'s example sentence.

Comment: I think you are right. I wasn't really looking at it from a marketing perspective before, but those are great suggestions. Thank you (and everyone) for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps versatile?

versatile - definition of versatile by the Free Online Dictionary ...

www.thefreedictionary.com/versatile

ver·sa·tile (vûr s -t l, -t l ). adj. 1. Capable of doing many things competently. 2. Having varied uses or serving many functions: "The most versatile of vegetables is ..

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't think that is quite the right word. My project only has one function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly I think you just want the word "useful".

> This project ... will be useful to as many people as possible (as many people as meet the requirements to use the project).

It sounds like you're saying is "if someone *could* use this project, it would be useful". Well, that's the definition of something being useful!

Answer (score 1):

Not one word, but "broadly applicable"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work without some rephrasing of your point, but perhaps "cross-cutting" would fit?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an appropriate word but probably - **multifunctional**..?

Comment: Desert - Please read Brit's comment under MizLaT's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A boiler performs a single function: producing steam.

It is used in every kind of factory. Each of which may use it in its own way.

For the boiler-maker, it is just a product. For the market, it is the most versatile equipment.

To take your product places, think marketing.

Answer (score 0):

Jane Austen wrote something like "universally pleasing". Well, "universally useful " or "applicable" might be interesting...